# See all $N$ events in $N$ trials

Tags: probability

There are $N$ distinct events.

Each round, one is randomly chosen with probability $1/N$.

QUESTION
What is the probability that in $ N $ rounds, all $ N$ events have been seen?

MY ATTEMPT

Probability of a particular sequence containing all $N$ events is $(1/N)^N$

But there’s more than one ordering i.e. $N! $ total orderings

So $N!\cdot (1/N)^N$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in a comment, your solution is correct.

Comment: How do I mark it as answered? Should I create an answer and copy-paste or accept this answer as the answer?

Comment: @Maximus1987: You can accept this answer as the answer if you're satisfied with it. I just made it community wiki because others had already answered in the comments, so it wasn't my work.